# how to make webkit scrollbar -- visible

Tags: html, css

In my HTML GUI their is 3 section :---

- Horizontally top (class of `div` is `scrollable`  --- &  --- ID of `div` is
  `Images`)
- Vertically Left  (class of `div` is  `scrollableMenu`  --- &  --- ID of
  `div` is `menu`)
- Central area     (class of `div` is  `scrollableCenter`  --- &  --- ID of `div` is center)

  1. When i press button-1 my jQuery code (using hide/show method)
     shows 7 input type images of class-1 in the Div scrollableMenu .
  2. When i press button-2 my jQuery code (using hide/show method)
     shows 8 input type images of class-2 in the Div scrollableMenu .
  3. When i press button-3 my jQuery code (using hide/show method)
     shows 3 input type images of class-3 in the Div scrollableMenu .
  4. When i press button-4 my jQuery code (using hide/show method)
     shows 4 input type images of class-1 in the Div scrollableMenu .

At present I only have webkit scrollbar running vertically downward along DIV scrollableMenu.
Thats as per my requirement i.e I only need webkit scrollbar running vertically downward for div scrollableMenu .

**Problem** I am facing is, in case 3 & 4 my webkit scrollbar becomes unvisible.

Is it possible that my webkit-scrollbar-track running vertically downward remains visible even if numbers of input type images are less **?**
Which property do I have to add to at least make my webkit-scrollbar-track visible **?**

---

### GUI view :

```
=========================================================

 Button-1   Button-2   Button-3    Button-4  Button-5

=========================================================
                 ||
                 ||
                 ||
      DIV        ||
 scrollableMenu  ||
                 ||
                 ||
                 ||
                 ||
                 ||
=========================================================
```

---

### CSS:

```
div.scrollable {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

div.scrollableMenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

div.scrollableCenter {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#images {
    background-color:#888686;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

#Menu {
    background-color:#292B3B;
    position:absolute;
    top:115px;
    bottom:20px;
    left:0;
    width:250px;
}
#center {
    background-color:#292B3B;
    position:absolute;
    top:115px;
    left:250px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:20px;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background-color: #DDDFED;
      border-radius: 20px;

}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color: #DDDFED;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
} 

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
      background-color: #CCC9DA;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to have only the vertical (y) scrollbar visible.
Not the horizontal (x).

All you need to do is define the position (x or y) of the scrollbar:

```
div.scrollableMenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll; /*(-y) here defines the direction of the scrollbar*/
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

If for some reason the bottom scrollbar still appears, use `overflow-x: hidden`.

**Edit**:

 
*A quick note: 
(y) = Vertical  
(x) = Horizontal*

---

### [Read more about CSS `overflow` property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the scrollbar on the left div scrollableMenu to be visible. Please use     `overflow: scroll;` for the scrollbar to be visible.

```
div.scrollableMenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Modified: `overflow: scroll;` to `overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden;`.

Comment: yes i have tried this but the problem with it is that --- scrollbar also becomes visible at the bottom of the div which i do not want...

Comment: Actually i want only vertically running scroll track visible with same color as webkit-scrollbar-track ... ?

Comment: Try `overflow-y: scroll;` and `overflow-x: hidden`. But I guess you'll only need the first one.

Comment: @Katoch Modified the css based on your requirement.